# Multiple users, actively working on separate working branches on Git

Tags: git

My company is using Git, and we just have a shared folder as our repo. I cannot seem to be able to get to the stage where I can have user a, on branch a, whilst user b is on branch b.

When I'm logged on as user a and checkout branch a, if user b had already checked out on branch b and was happily sitting on branch b, his working branch will immediately change to branch a.

Is this the way Git is supposed to work, or am I missing something completely?

It's been  suggested to me, that each user has to make a separate clone each to work off, but this will not work for the system that we have in place. In the directory that we have the initial Git repository, I'll say it's at `/I/shared/testsys` we have an auto compiler that runs over that, so you make a change or edit, then  in a browser we go to `http://ourserver/testsys/mynicepgm.aspx` and it  compiles on the fly and you can immediately see your changes that you have made. If each developer has to take a copy, how can he see his change without first pushing it back to that area? Surely that makes the whole concept of branching pretty redundant?

Comment: Each user has to use an own cloned copy of the main repository. Working on the same repository using a shared folder is wrong.

Comment: Git is _distributed_ version control software. It’s be very good if each person cloned their own copy of the repo.

Comment: Thank you for both your answers.. I did not know that.

Comment: Though why I was marked down for not knowing  something is beyond me..

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but you can easily search how Git works online before asking.

Comment: @jbapbecker As for the compilation, it sounds like what you want is [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), for which there are plenty of tools.

Comment: Well,the reason for my question was because git doesn't work in an obvious way out of the box  for us, because we have a compiler sitting on and IFS area on an iseries box and that's where the changes need to be in order to enable testing of what you have coded..without that, you've literally no clue if your coding works or not.. So in my defence, what was I supposed to think?